# Furnace sometimes does not start

Tags: hvac

I have a 5 year old Broan furnace  model M7RL 072A AW  downflow condensing gas furnace. Here's the furnace startup sequence:

- pump runs
- ignitor glows
- hear the click of the gas valve opening
- fires up
- runs 4 seconds
- shuts down

The next 2-3 attempts it starts and runs fine, then it does it again. It never shows any codes. I have replaced the flame sensor , but still does it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Might there be a draft problem? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I have a different furnace that did the same thing. It turned out the the flue draft sensor relay was bad. The draft fan worked, the sensor worked, but the relay was bad. I had to replace the control board. I'm only leaving this as a comment because the board is expensive and needed much more testing than what you've done to isolate it, just giving a possibility to check.